# Transformation for sitemap is not working with MSBUILD

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I am using MSBUILD to autodeploy from TFS. My application has three files for which I need XML transformation.
1. web.config
2. breadcrumb.sitemap
3. main.sitemap

I am having separate files for every configuration (Debug, Release, Dev, Prod). Only Web.config is getting transformed with corresponding configuration while other two are not transformed. On the server, if I see the build, it has only web.config file while for other two all (parent as well as child files) are present.

Can anybody tell me why XML transformation is working only for web.config not for breadcrumb and main.sitemap?

Thanks
Ashwani

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [XmlPreprocess tool](http://xmlpreprocess.codeplex.com/) for config files manipulation. It is using one mapping file for multiple environments. You can edit mapping file by Excel. It is very easy to use.
You can update your scripts to use xmlpreprocess and use configuration (debug, dev, prod,...) as a parameter for it...